# Error al instalar angular/material en Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, vscode

Espero me puedan apoyar, creé aplicacion con API que quiero conectar con angular, a la hora de instalar con el comando `ng add @angular/material@14.2.7` me sale este error:

```
No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\HectorEduardoPedroza\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1. 
El archivo 
C:\Users\HectorEduardoPedroza\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 no está firmado digitalmente. 
No se puede ejecutar este script en el sistema actual. Para   
obtener más información acerca de la ejecución de scripts y la configuración de la 
directiva de ejecución, consulta about_Execution_Policies en      
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ ng add @angular/material@14.2.7
```

Pero ya tengo el MachinePolicy y el LocalMachine habilitados, pero me sigue dando ese error, saben por que me lo esta dando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y usando `npm i @angular/material@14.2.7`?

Comment: Si, lo chistoso es que en mi visual no lo reconoce pero al usar cmd de mi proyecto si puedo utilizarlo.

Comment: No estarás usando Powershell dentro de VS Code?

Comment: Si, esa estoy utilizando, esta mal?

Comment: No es que esté mal, pero parece que Powershell bloquea algo. Prueba borrando el archivo que te dice ahí (ng.ps1) o usa la cmd dentro de VS Code.

Comment: Muchas gracias Rene, voy hacerlo.